# how to remove only the duplication file under some directory ( with the same cksum )

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, solaris

I build the following script in order to remove files that are  with the same cksum ( or content )

The problem is that the script can remove files twice as the following example ( output  )

My target is to remove only the duplication file and not the source file ,

SCRIPT OUTPUT:

```
  Starting:
  Same: /tmp/File_inventury.out /tmp/File_inventury.out.1
  Remove: /tmp/File_inventury.out.1
  Same: /tmp/File_inventury.out.1 /tmp/File_inventury.out
  Remove: /tmp/File_inventury.out
  Same: /tmp/File_inventury.out.2 /tmp/File_inventury.out.3
  Remove: /tmp/File_inventury.out.3
  Same: /tmp/File_inventury.out.3 /tmp/File_inventury.out.2
  Remove: /tmp/File_inventury.out.2
  Same: /tmp/File_inventury.out.4 /tmp/File_inventury.out
  Remove: /tmp/File_inventury.out
  Done.
```

.

MY SCRIPT:

```
 #!/bin/bash
  DIR="/tmp"
 echo "Starting:"
  for file1 in ${DIR}/File_inventury.out*; do
    for file2 in ${DIR}/File_inventury.out*; do
            if [ $file1 != $file2 ]; then
                    diff "$file1" "$file2" 1>/dev/null
                    STAT=$?
                    if [ $STAT -eq 0 ]
                     then
                            echo "Same: $file1 $file2"
                            echo "Remove: $file2"
                            rm "$file1"
                            break
                    fi
            fi
    done
 done
 echo "Done."
```

.

In any case I want to ear – other options about how to remove files that are with the same content or cksum  ( actually need only to remove the duplication file and not the primary file )

please advice how we can do that under solaris OS , ( options for example - find one liner , awk , sed ... etc )

Comment: As the file contents are same, how do you find which is the source? By the filename or modification date? If so, you'll only need to compare it before deciding which to remove.

Comment: Also, your current method seems low in efficiency, especially when the files are large: imagine there're `n` distinct files, and your script would read them for about `2*n*n` times.

Comment: I dont have in my solaris machine the fdupes command !

Comment: You can [get and install it](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes). This will be way easier and more efficient than hacking up your own version.

Comment: sorry I cant , because  we not allowed to do this on customor machine

Comment: yes starrify - I agree and thats because I want to ear other option? that can be more efficiency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version should be more efficient. I was nervous about `paste` matching the correct rows, but it looks like [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/glob.html) specifies that glob'ing is sorted by default.

```
for i in *; do
    date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%TZ -r "$i";
done > .stat;         #store the last modification time in a sortable format
cksum * > .cksum;     #store the cksum, size, and filename
paste .stat .cksum |  #data for each file, 1 per row
    sort |            #sort by mtime so original comes first
    awk '{
        if($2 in f)
            system("rm -v " $4); #rm if we have seen an occurrence of this cksum
        else
            f[$2]++              #count the first occurrence
    }'
```

This should run in `O(n * log(n))` time, reading each file only once.

You can put this in a shell script as:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *; do
    date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%TZ -r "$i";
done > .stat;
cksum * > .cksum;
paste .stat .cksum | sort | awk '{if($2 in f) system("rm -v " $4); else f[$2]++}';
rm .stat .cksum;
exit 0;
```

Or do it as a one-liner:

```
for i in *; do date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%TZ -r "$i"; done > .stat; cksum * > .cksum; paste .stat .cksum | sort | awk '{if($2 in f) system("rm -v " $4); else f[$2]++}'; rm .stat .cksum;
```

Comment: sorry but cant understand what I need to do with your code ? , what I need to do with awk ?

Comment: Hold on, don't use it yet. I have an error in my `sort` syntax, but then I'll show this as a bash script.

Comment: Okay... I've tried to limit myself to the POSIX specs of the utilities. Let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I used an array as index map. So I think it is just O(n) ?

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=()
dels=()
for f in $1; do
  read ck x fn <<< $(cksum $f)
  if [[ -z ${arr[$ck]} ]]; then 
    arr[$ck]=$fn
  else
    echo "Same: ${arr[$ck]} $fn"
    echo "Remove: $fn"
    rm $fn
  fi
done
```